# Google Analytics custom reports: do I need to check for malware?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I need some information from Google Analytics (for example: graphing users' geographical origin through time) that I could not find in my Analytics existing page. I was pointed to the Analytics Solutions Gallery:

https://www.google.com/analytics/gallery/

But before I start importing stuff from there into my account, I'd like to know: can these third-party created dashboards, custom reports, etc. contain malware?

Sorry if this seems a naive question, but I just discovered this whole ecosystem, and am still unclear about what these custom reports are, from a technical POV. Are they just tools created by combining Analytics' existing options, or can they contain custom Javascript code (for example)? (Because in the latter case, they certainly could have malware).

Answer (score 1):

When you try to create one of these shared reports, you're asked for a URL - it's not like someone is uploading a file to be executed. This URL is specified to be from Google Analytics directly.

Hence the reports cannot contain malware as such.